# Component styles not working properly - Vuetify

Tags: css, vue.js, components, vuetify.js

I am using Vuetify as the component framework of my Vue 2 app. While some styling such as with the `v-card` component and properties like `elevation` work, some components do not have the correct styling.

For example, in the following code I am using a simple `v-chip`.

```
<v-chip style="background-color:rgb(181 240 152);padding: 8px;"> 
   Group {{ groupNo }} ({{ group.length }} Participants)
</v-chip>
```

I added some in-line styling for development, which works. However, none of the Vuetify component properties, which can be found [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/chips/#closable), used to style the chip work. The chip itself just displays as a rectangular box no matter what Vuetify properties I use.

I don't know why some of the styling works and some doesn't. If anyone has any ideas I'd much appreciate it.

**EDIT**

I have found the following in the console css:

```
.theme--light .v-chip.v-chip {
    border-radius: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: thin;
}
```

So, the `boder-radius` is defaulting to 0. I can use the above css classes to manually add the `border-radius` back to the `v-chip` by adding this to the component css:

```
  .theme--light .v-chip.v-chip {
    border-radius: 10px !important;
   }
```

But it feels very hacky to me. I am not sure why it defaults to 0 when the border-radius is a key part of the `v-chip` styling.

Comment: Can you please tell me what styling are you expecting for this chip?

Comment: @NehaSoni I edited my question to add more detail on the expected styling. Basically, what I expect at least is the `border-radius` that is standard for a chip element. As you can see, I can add it myself but I'd rather Vuetify did it for me. Thanks!

Comment: Umm, It should not happen because v-chip by default has the border-radius classes, it is only removed when we apply the `label` attribute on it. Can you tell who is the parent of this v-chip? Also, did you add any custom class for the border anywhere in the root scope or something? It might be a case of leaking.

Comment: The fastest way here would be to debug it via the devtools elements inspector to see which properties the chip inherits. Maybe you have some CSS collision or another library overriding those specific variables for some reason.